# how to set onclick in CarouselPicker

Tags: android

In the oode below the Carousel is automatically having taking a intent activity when it is on certain postion but i want to make it as a onclick function not automatically

```
CarouselPicker carouselPicker1 = (CarouselPicker)v.findViewById( R.id.carouselPicker1 );
        List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> itemsImages = new ArrayList<>();
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.website_design));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.digital_marketing));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.domain_registration));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.graphic));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.mob));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.server));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.software_development));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.ontent));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.ssl));
//        CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this,itemsImages,0);
        CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this.getContext(),itemsImages,0);
        carouselPicker1.setAdapter(imageAdapter);        

carouselPicker1.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    if(position == 0){
                        startActivity(new    Intent(getActivity(), website_designing.class));
                    }
                    else if(position == 1){
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), digital_marketing.class));
                    }
                    //position of the selected item
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: onPageSelected(int position) is execued when view pager is scrolled to that position. For click you need to implement onClicklistener to view of viewpager.

Comment: can you help me with the sample code

Comment: Please post your full code , how you are setting views to Carousel.

Comment: You will have to set the click listeners on the individual objects of the carouselPicker rather than having it in the onPageSelected. Paste the code for the adapter as well

Comment: there is no adapter class in this